# how to display all tables name from mysql database using php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

how to display all tables name from mysql database using php? I am using this syntax.. can anybody guide me where i m wrong.. thanks in advance

```
    <?php

$db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','realestate');

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($db))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  else 
  {
  echo "Successfully connected to database.</br>";
  }

  $result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM 'realestate'");

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row[0];
  }


  ?>
```

Comment: Do you get an error? A white screen? What does `mysql_error()` give you?

Comment: select from information_schema

Comment: I'm not pretty sure, but I guess the quotes are unnecessary at database name in your query. Also you could do "SHOW TABLES" only as well, because database name was already specified.

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\00000\tables2.php on line 17

Answer (score 2):

1.You are mixing mysqli with mysql

2.Use backticks for table,database or column names

```
SHOW TABLES FROM `realestate`
```

Comment: sir, its giving me error that mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean  given and all